# Formula for calculating instantaneous power in pure inductive and pure capacitive circuit

Tags: power, capacitor, inductor, formula-derivation

According to the material provided by a faculty this is what the formulas were and how they were derived.
[image]

[image]

According to the derivation we did in class, we were getting:
P = -V<sub>rms</sub>I<sub>rms</sub>sin 2ωt for pure inductive circuit because we took I = I<sub>m</sub>sinωt-π/2 and V = V<sub>m</sub>sinωt

and 
P = V<sub>rms</sub>I<sub>rms</sub>sin 2ωt for pure capacitive circuit because we took I = I<sub>m</sub>sinωt+π/2 and V = V<sub>m</sub>sinωt

I understand the basic idea; current lags behind applied voltage by 90 degree in inductive and the opposite happens in capacitive circuit. So it shouldn't matter how V and I are written as? If I'm asked to calculate the instantaneous power won't the two formulas give different answers? According to the formula we derived in class, for example if we get x for instantaneous power in the capacitive circuit, we'll get -x for by using the formula given in the faculty material. How can that be different?

Comment: Please call it power waveform or instantaneous power rather than just power. When we talk about power we usually mean average power and, of course, the average power in both those waveforms are zero.

Comment: @Andyaka got it. i've edited it

Comment: They are different answers because they are meant to be different.

Comment: @Andyaka im not sure i understand.  Can you explain a bit more?

according to the formula we derived in class, for example if we get x for instantaneous power in the capactitve circuit, we'll get -x for by using the formula given in the faculty material. How can that be different?

Comment: Ah, I think you need to be clearer in your question.

Comment: Look at the waveforms.  The - means inductive reactive power is opposite to capacitive reactive power.  Different or possibly same magnitude sine waves, but 180 degrees out of phase.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat i've edited my original question to make it clearer; i didn't frame it well. What I meant to ask was: 

According to the formula we derived in class, for example if we get x for instantaneous power in the capacitive circuit, we'll get -x for by using the formula given in the faculty material. How can that be different?

Comment: Put a L and C in series.  Line up both sets of waveforms.  What is the average instantaneous power?  Answer: 0  The capacitor supplies leading reactive power for the lagging reactive power of the inductor.